# Python: Can I get None's attribute from the descriptor's __get__?

Tags: python, attributes, nonetype, magic-methods, descriptor

I have this callable object `bool_getter := vars(type(None))["__bool__"].__get__` (of type `types.MethodWrapperType`).  Is there a way to make this `bool_getter` return `None`'s method `None.__bool__` by calling it?  I didn't figure it out after trying a few obvious choices.  (The value of `None.__bool__` is not identical every time the expression is evaluated, so I want `bool_getter` to return not the identical but just an equal object.)

In case the question didn't make full sense to you, please consider doing one of the following things.

1. Please show me a way to construct an iterable `args` and a mapping `kwargs` such that you get an object `value := bool_getter(*args, **kwargs)` successfully, and that `value` will be equal to `boolNone := None.__bool__`.  That is, `type(value)` should be `type(boolNone)`, namely, `types.MethodWrapperType` and `value == boolNone` must be `True`.  (In my experience, `boolNone` always satisfies `boolNone == None.__bool__`.)
2. If that's impossible to do, please show me how you can tell it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  The help to which you gave me a link started with "When asking a debugging question, ...", but I'm confused what may have made you think mine was a debugging question.

Comment: I've added a paragraph.  I hope it's useful to some people if redundant to some others.